# Eclipse showing proper dependencies, but mvn package produces WAR with out-dated dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, war

I'm working with a web app, called A, using maven, in eclipse, going between using m2e eclipse plugin and command line maven.

A depends on a custom library B, which is installed in the local repo. A details this dependency in its `pom.xml`

**When I test the app in eclipse using eclipse's Tomcat, everything is fine** -- the up-to-date version of B is used, and I see so in Maven dependencies folder.

**But for some reason, when I go to command line and run `mvn package`, the resulting WAR uses out-dated version of B.** I can tell because when I get it deployed to app server, its logging and functionality is broken in a specific way that was fixed in a newer version of B.

Is there any way for me to debug what's going on here? What is eclipse doing that `mvn package` is not including?

Project definition:

```
<groupId>org.com.web</groupId>
<artifactId>DocImgTransfer_Servlet</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Dependency on lib that is somehow getting old version:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>DocImgTransfer</groupId>
  <artifactId>DocImgTransfer</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

So really 3 questions:

1. If it is just some issue with maven grabbing the wrong version from local repo, is there a way for me to tell Maven to double-check the dependency version it's pulling in?
2. Will `mvn clean` or `mvn package -U` possibly help in this case at all?
3. Is the only advice to just  double-check groupId, artifactId, version in `pom.xml`?

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml?

Comment: this is kind of hilarious but I'm at my grandma's for thanksgiving and the source code is on an EC2 instance in AWS, and I can only get to it on my other laptop but she has no wi fi/ethernet cable too big for my lap top! So... for now I can't show the pom.xml but I will try soon. Any possible hints at debugging in the mean time? just check out the pom.xml? Can you comment on my 1. 2. or 3. question? thanks!

Comment: I am using Ubuntu, and all my jars are stored in repository folder...I don't know which one it is for u, why dont you try deleting the folder containing all jar's and just do mvn update.

Comment: I'm also on Ubuntu. the m2 repo is located in `/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository`. The location of the specific jar is something like `/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/.../CustomJar/CustomatJar-1.0.0.jar` -- what exactly are you suggesting I delete before running `mvn update`? What will that achieve?

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is just some issue with maven grabbing the wrong version from local repo, is there a way for me to tell Maven to double-check the dependency version it's pulling in?

a) Is your CustomatJar-1.0.0.jar version that eclipse is referring to same as maven is picking up or is maven picking up an older version?
i.e. Do you own the code for CustomatJar and are you just updating it v/s the one getting packed in war is truly an older version e.g. CustomatJar-0.0.5

i) You could tell by just unzipping the war and seeing which version is packed inside the jar.

ii) mvn dependency:dependency would tell you which dependencies maven command line thinks should be packed. [more info](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/)

2. Is the only advice to just double-check groupId, artifactId, version in pom.xml?

Could you server have got an older version of CustomatJar in say it's lib?
You did double check your POM.xml already ... correct?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you said in `a)` -- CustomJar-1.0.0 is developed by me, installed in local repository (/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository). Two diff versions, `1.0.0` listed in `pom.xml` and working in eclipse tomcat test, but `mvn package` seems to end up using older version, `1.0-SNAPSHOT`. I have double-checked `pom.xml`. I will try `mvn dependency:dependency` and other suggestions from that link, and I will try to unzip the resulting war to check out the version packed inside. Would runnin `mvn clean` or `mvn package` with `-U` possibly help? Or is that unrelated? Thanks~!

Comment: "mvn clean or mvn package with -U"

seems unrelated to your problem. If you have 1.0.0 listed in your POM, that is the one that should get picked up. What do you see when you unzip?